# Использовать временную функцию в блоке PL/SQL, в SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Структура блока такая:

```
declare
*переменые*
  function somefunc...
  begin
    ...
  end
begin
  ...
  SELECT somefunc(...) into temp FROM ...
  ...
end
```

В таком раскладе нельзя использовать временную функцию внутри SQL-запроса. Как обойти это ограничение?

Comment: временных функций не бывает. Зато практически любой расчет, который способна делать функция можно написать прямо в запросе

Comment: Версия оракла у вас какая? В 12-й версии есть "временные функции".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В SQL использовать не получится, т.к. для этого функцию нужно где-нибудь объявить.

Можно присвоить значение переменной и затем использовать ее:

```
v_temp := somefunc(...)
```

Comment: Да, но в параметр функции передается именно значение из селекта, заранее он не известен. Я сейчас решил это, используя цикл FOR, где запрос оставил в курсоре, а уже в теле цикла работаю с каждой строкой.

Comment: @ВиталийЯндулов Тоже вариант. Но, имхо, проще объявить функцию глобально.

Answer (score 4):

TL;DR: Никак, функции объявленные внутри анонимного блока недоступны интерпретатору SQL. Чтобы их можно было вызвать в SQL, они должны быть объявлены как объекты на уровне схемы:

```
create or replace function foo (par number) return number is begin return null; end;
```

или как пакетные функции в спецификации пакета:

```
create or replace package pkg as 
    function foo (par number) return number;
end;
```

Пока не будут даны `execute` права другим пользователям БД, эти функции никому, кроме того, кто их объявил, не видны. Поэтому, никаких преимуществ объявления функций в анонимном блоке нет.

---

Если всё же в анонимном блоке, то можно вместо вызова функции в SQL передать всю выборку как параметр в функцию:

```sql
declare
    c sys_refcursor; 
    function fun (c sys_refcursor) return number is
        ret number;
    begin
        fetch c into ret;
        close c;
        return ret;
    end;
begin 
    open c for select 1 from dual;
    dbms_output.put_line ('ret='||fun (c)); 
end;
/
```

> ret=1

Answer (score 2):

Если объявление на уровне схемы нежелательно и интересна именно временная функция (например, для украшения кода), то переместите объявление функции прямо в запрос.
Так она будет видна интерпретатору SQL для данного запроса:

```sql
declare
    res sys.odciVarchar2List;
begin
    execute immediate q'[
    with 
    function somefunc (arg varchar2) return varchar2 is
    begin 
        return 'result='||arg;
    end;
    data as (
        select column_value arg from sys.odciVarchar2List ('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc') 
    )
    select somefunc (arg) res 
    from data
    ]' bulk collect into res;
    for idx in 1..res.count loop dbms_output.put_line (res (idx)); end loop;
end
;
/
```

> result=aaa
>   result=bbb
>   result=ccc

В PL/SQL блоке такой запрос нельзя обявить статическим. Но так, как анонимный блок сам по себе является динамическим запросом, то это не играет никакой роли.

<sub>Доступно начиная с 12c</sub>